# Add 2 Taxonomies to Custom Post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom post type "beers" and added a custom taxonomy "distributor" as a category (see below)

```
register_taxonomy("distributor", array("beers"), array(
                    "hierarchical" => true, 
                    "label" => "Distributors", 
                    "singular_label" => "Distributors", 
                    "rewrite" => array(  
                    'slug' => 'filter',  
                    'hierarchical' => true  
                )  
            )
```

How can I add an additional taxonomy to this? Maybe in form of a tag so a post can be filtered filtered even further.

Comment: I think this will help you, looking for "Example" http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: Depending on the information you are storing and how you intend to filter your searches, using post meta data may make more sense than using additional taxonomies. It can be much easier to pin-point a post using `meta_query`. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters